# How to run Ethernet cable along a brick wall?

Tags: wiring

I want to run an Ethernet wire from the living room where my TV and router are to the basement where my office is. The problem is that when I lifted the drop ceiling in the basement, I saw that the drywall is attached directly to the brick wall (actually looks like concrete blocks) that I share with my neighbor. 
The wall to the right is where the cable hookup is and that goes down to the basement as well.
Is there a way to run the cable along that brick wall or should I drop the Ethernet cable in the cable hookup box?

Edit:This is interior wall

Comment: Have you considered powerline networking?

Answer (score 1):

There are [cable clamps](http://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=CUa8rU4pjVa6ADdDA-QP93oHwCYGD08MG4bmbt4MBkenW56ICCAYQAigDYMneu4zYpIwRoAGr2ab_A8gBB6oEJk_QOTaL02L2JPAZLqPrJeE6SiFNjf-giYsnZGYbQiygquFpthc9wAUFoAYmgAe9plmIBwGQBwKoB6a-G9gHAeASw6XA6-3UytZe&sig=AOD64_3oquI1CkbSxtxz8N4tpkX6tJMJXw&ctype=5&clui=14&rct=j&q=&ved=0CHwQuxc&adurl=http://www.solidsignal.com/pview.asp%3Fp%3DWCMNC-03664%26utm_campaign%3Dbase%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_source%3Dgoogle_base) available that have nails suitable for masonry walls

Comment: This is false, all cables need to secured and supported. See NEC 800.24.

Comment: My apologies, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you can run the Ethernet to the basement through the cable box, why not just do that? Both the co-ax and the Ethernet cables are low voltage. There's no problem running them together in the same box and/or conduit.

If you run the Ethernet cable exposed along the wall, it won't cause data transmission problems, but it won't be attractive and you'll have to secure the cable to the drywall or the concrete blocks. If this is all indoors, you're not going to have a problem with the cable jacket breaking down. Although you can obtain UV resistant and direct-bury Ethernet cable if there's going to be exterior exposure.

Whether it's interior or exterior, you could also consider using conduit.

Bear in mind that Ethernet requires a minimum 3" bend radius--don't kink the cable or bend it at a sharp angle around or within any corners or you'll have data transmission problems (or failure).

Comment: The TV and router are about 10 feet from the cable box. I'm already running cables along the baseboard but I was thinking to mount the TV on the wall, so I was hoping I can put a cable box in the wall behind it for cleaner look.

Comment: If the sheetrock is attached (glued?) directly to the concrete block wall and you want some kind of raceway behind the sheetrock, you might want to consider framing a wall up against the existing wall with 2x4's, or use 2x2's as firring attached to the blocks, which would still give you enough room for shallow boxes. That way, you could run both low-voltage cable and electricity (not together in the same box) for a nice, clean look.

Answer (score 0):

If the flooring has has trim it is very easy to shimmy off just enough to drill a 1/4" hole for the cable.  You can the leave as is or be more professional and cut in a box and snake the cable back around to it. ( requires you to know how to make cat5 connections )

But otherwise yes perfectly fine to run along a brick wall.  Just might break down faster from the elements, if that worries you then run in conduit

Comment: What elements? This appears to be an interior party wall "I share with my neighbor."